# How to reproduce this change in pull request history?

Tags: git, branch, rebase, pull-request, git-commit

I would like to know all the possible ways a PR could have such a history. Is it possible achieve it without `git commit --amend --author="xxx"`?

I had some work done on the branches and when I came back I found all my commits to have a different author `<my-coworker>`. The commits were exactly the same. Names and changes.

**Case 1:**

**Original:**

```
<my-user> opens a PR
<my-user> added N commits:
* <my-commit-1> by <my-user>
* <my-commit-2> by <my-user>
```

I later come back to find out the following state under the same PR:

**New:**

```
<my-user> opens a PRa
<my-coworker> force pushed <this-prs-branch> from <ref> to <ref>
<my-coworker> added N commits:
* <my-commit-1> by <my-coworker>
* <my-commit-2> by <my-coworker>
* Other commits by <my-coworker>
<my-coworker> force pushed <this-branch> from <ref> to <ref>
```

**Case 2:**

**Original:**

```
<my-user> opens a PR
<my-user> added N commits:
* <my-commit-1> by <my-user>
* <my-commit-2> by <my-user>
```

I later come back to find out the following state under the same PR:

**New:**

```
<my-user> opens a PR
<my-coworker> added N commits:
* <my-commit-1> by <my-coworker>
* <my-commit-2> by <my-coworker>
* Other commits by <my-coworker>
<my-coworker> force pushed <this-prs-branch> from <ref> to <ref>
```

I could reproduce case 2 by doing `git commit --amend --author='<another-author>`. My coworker has told me that the author change happened because of a rebase of this feature branch on master. I have tried doing interactive rebases using 2 different users and conflicting changes. And experimented with accepting a mix of changes during rebases. All I could achieve were commits with `<my-user> authored and <another-user> committed`. But not a 'clean' commit by `<another-user>`. Have I missed something? Bringing any clarity to this issue would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: It depends on the way the coworker rebased. The specific tools/commands they used would give you the answers you need. I'd suggest asking them.

Comment: an easy way to add additional commits on top of the PR is to push commits to the branch that created the pr. Depending on what your branching strategy is, this could be within the same repo or with separate repos.

Comment: Thanks for your comments! @RomainValeri, could you pls provide at least one example of how this could be achieved? If it's git rebase which it was at the end of the day, then how is it possible for the author to change?

Comment: @burn From the rebase [doc](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase#_interactive_mode): "*By replacing the command "pick" with the command "edit", you can tell git rebase to stop after applying that commit, so that you can edit the files and/or the commit message, amend the commit, and continue rebasing.*" If you can amend a commit, you can change anything in it. Author included.

Comment: @RomainValeri, thank you for the explanation! So it is as I thought. No way to **just** run a rebase and have the authors change